# Python xlib warp_pointer not working properly inside games

Tags: python, mouse, xlib

I am trying to change the mouse pointer using python xlib. I successfully did it using warp_pointer. But when i try to play any games like Secret Maryo Chronicles, the mouse pointer moves to the rightmost corner of the screen and not the specified location. Why is it so? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to accomplish with warp_pointer? How are you using it with the games you're trying it on?

Comment: With warp_pointer i'm trying to move the mouse pointer any particular position on the screen. It works fine on the desktop ( Ubuntu in my case). But when i start a game the program works but the mouse pointer moves to the lower right corner of the screen

Answer (score 3):

It looks like contrary to what the documentation says, it is an absolute coordinate, not an
offset.

I tried this and it worked as expected if you think of coordinates as absolute coordinate with 1,1 (or 0,0 ) starting at the top left corner of the window.

```
from Xlib import X, display
import time

d = display.Display()
s = d.screen()
root = s.root
root.warp_pointer(500,500)
d.sync()

time.sleep( 5 )
root.warp_pointer(250,250)
d.sync()

time.sleep( 5 )
root.warp_pointer(100,100)
d.sync()

time.sleep( 5 )
root.warp_pointer(250,250)
d.sync()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SMC. It may be that it uses warp_pointer itself. I know a lot of games do to simulate the relative motion support only recently introduced to XInput and I think some of them use it to stash the mouse "out of the way". Have you tried it with games that do different things with the mouse?